# Cant add NSArray to NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a mutlidimensional NSDictionary, and am having problems adding an array to it. My dictionary structure looks like this: (taken by NSLogging the dictionary)

```
{
    Downloaded =     {
        017315 = "2013-01-16 11:26:33 +0000";
    };
    Projects =  (
        {
            Docs = { };
            "Last Downloaded" = "2013-01-16 10:16:05 +0000";
            "Project Name" = "Baring Australia Fund";
        }
    );
}
```

I am trying to add a new array to the "Docs" dictionary. The code I am using is

```
[[[[myDict objectForKey:@"Projects"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Docs"] setObject:[NSMutableArray array] forKey:@"test"];
```

This is failing with the following error

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7592df0'

If I try to add a Dictionary to the Docs key instead of an array using the code below, it works.

```
[[[[myDict objectForKey:@"Projects"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Docs"] setObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] forKey:@"test"];
```

In addition, I am also able to add the new array to the first "Projects" array item, just not to the Docs object within it.

What am I doing wrong, and why is this not working?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the `Projects` array is a `NSMutableArray` and not an `NSArray` (mutability being the issue here).

Comment: It is Mutable for sure, as he is able to add dictionary in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[[myDict objectForKey:@"Projects"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Docs"]` this is returning you an array.

And you are using setObject:forKey: in this array.

`[someArray setObject: forKey:]` is what your compiler see and throwing error.

EDIT:

I checked your code, it is fine. and the above error is coming from some other places.

I mimic-ed your code and it works fine. Have a look, what i tested:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *myDict=[NSMutableDictionary new];

NSMutableDictionary *downloadedDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"2013-01-16 11:26:33 +0000" forKey:@"017315"];
[myDict setObject:downloadedDict forKey:@"Downloaded"];

NSMutableDictionary *docsDict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
NSMutableDictionary *emptyDict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
[docsDict setObject:emptyDict forKey:@"Docs"];
[docsDict setObject:@"2013-01-16 10:16:05 +0000" forKey:@"Last Downloaded"];
[docsDict setObject:@"Baring Australia Fund" forKey:@"Project Name"];
NSMutableArray *projects=[NSMutableArray new];
[projects addObject:docsDict];


[myDict setObject:projects forKey:@"Projects"];

// NSLog(@"%@",mainDict);
//[[[[myDict objectForKey:@"Projects"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Docs"] setObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] forKey:@"test"];
[[[[myDict objectForKey:@"Projects"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Docs"] setObject:[NSMutableArray array] forKey:@"test"];

NSLog(@"%@",myDict);
```

Comment: Then, to use your own words: "he is able to add dictionary in it".

Comment: The @"Docs" key is a Dictionary, not an Array. I confirmed that by testing with NSLog(@"%i", [[[[myDict objectForKey:@"Projects"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Docs"] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]);

Comment: As per your error, i wrote those. Wait I am creating same level of dictionary and will check...and will come to you.

Comment: @user857903 : check my update and kindly let me know, if my structure same as yours?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was only working half day yesterday. Your code does indeed create the same structure as mine. I merged your and my structure line-by-line and it is identical.  It is very strange that I cannot add an object to my array, but I can to yours. The only difference between the two is that my array was created earlier in the process whereas yours is created on the fly. I will keep plugging away at it but at least you have confirmed that it should work. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Okay. I have made some progress on this. It seems the problem is actually with the key name I am passing to setObject:forKey method.  If I type a name in manually, it works, but if I retrieve the key name from another array (Which i am actually doing) it fails, even though it is type cast as a string.  Sorry for not giving all the information before, but I really didn't think for a minute that would be important. It was your code above that led me to discovering this, so thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best approach, given the complexity of the data you are storing (and both your and my apparent inability to cope with that complexity) is to reimplement this as a custom object where the object properties are implemented in a more concrete manner.

It will most likely pay for the effort required in no time at all.

**UPDATE** Some example objects (I don't have complete requirements, so this will be incomplete):

```
@interface Project : NSObject
{
    NSString *_name;
    NSMutableArray *_documents;   // Array of document names?
    NSDate *_lastDownloaded;
}

// @property for each ivar

@end

@interface Projects : NSObject
{
    NSDate *_lastDownloaded;
    NSMutableArray *_projects;     // Array of Project objects
}

// @property for each ivar

@end
```

Comment: Ya it is a better way. Could you please elaborate that which objects that he should take here. Some hint would be good.

Comment: I agree that objects would be much better, but this data is being written to, and read from a plist file which changes over the duration of the app session. Objects would work, but I would still ultimately need a nested array.